# How to trigger an UI action when the app is closed in React Native?

Tags: react-native, socket.io, agora.io, videocall

Apologies if my question is already answered in any other ways. I am very new to react-native with no knowledge of android or java.

I am trying to make a video conferencing app with react native. I used Agora for video calling and linked it with socket.io and react-native-callkeep for real time experience.

Now i am stuck in a situation where i have to make the app functional when someone is calling and the app is ""Closed"". Something like Whatsapp. I thought of implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notification. And though it will open the application in someway. But the application opens when user opens the notification.

Can anyone please help me with any of the following or better ideas:

```
1. Keep the socket io open even when app is closed 
Or 2. Open my application with incoming push notification (Without Opening It)
```

Please avoid abstruct answers as i am very new in this sector. I really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second method is the  way to go you can also look at this library called [react-native-callkeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) I think it fits your use-case as well.